# Windows 8 USB Wireless Adaptor

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, drivers, wireless-adapter

I just installed Windows 8 for a friend, but he uses a Wireless Adaptor from Netgear to connect to the internet. It is model WNA3100, and we need the Windows 8 Drivers for this.

It also says Wireless N-300 USB Adaptor.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the latest drivers and management program for that specific device - http://support.netgear.com/product/WNA3100

(Just click on Software Version 2.1 (Supports Win8) )

You may need to uninstall the original drivers entirely which you can use " Start > Programs > NETGEAR WNA3100 adapter > Uninstall NETGEAR WNA3100 adapter " OR use Windows Device Manager to remove.

It should be noted the official instructions say to remove the device before installing, so this is the first step I would take.

(Edited because specific Windows 8 drivers were found, rather than just the AIO)